# Unable to open .xlsx file after writing text into it using Open XML Format SDK 2.5

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml-sdk

```
public void OpenDxRecordsFormExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\DxRecordForm.xlsx",true);
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>();
            var sheet = sheets.First();

            WorksheetPart workSheetPart = ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart
                .GetPartById(sheet.Id));

            Cell headerCell = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference == "A1").First();
            headerCell.CellValue = new CellValue("NAME:" + "  " + "Test Text");

            workSheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            document.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }


    }
```

I am using above method to write text into one of the cells of an excel document (.xlsx). After executing above code, when I try to open the excel document, I get a dialog box saying
"Excel found unreadable content in the file. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook ? "
If I hit "Yes" to open the excel file, I get another message that excel was able to open the document after removing the unreadable content.

I can see the text in the A1 cell but I am not sure why is the message shown by excel while opening the document.

I am new to using the Open XML SDK for reading/writing into .xlsx files.

Comment: Don't ever use try/catch blocks that way. That hides all exceptions you may encounter, so you will never know what went wrong.

Comment: Hint: an XLSX file is an XML file. Open it in an XML editor, maybe even try to pretty print it. If the XML editor won't open it, then fall back to a text editor. Search for the text you tried to add, then try to figure out where you added it wrong. And next time, save a backup before modifying the file.